Parcel bundler code migration from v1 to v2
Please how can I convert this parcel bundler code from v1 to v2 "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js" The index.js is the entry point and I want it to bundle the code for me in a new bundle.js file inside public/js. I've tried couple of solutions, nothing worked.
I tried "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js", but it just bundles the code to ./public/js/index.js
I need to bundle the code inside ./public/js

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
